# Qual o problema de alocar memória com new e depois não apagar?

Tags: c++

O que pode acontecer se eu usar o new para alocar memória e depois não liberar ela?

E quando é na situação abaixo, que eu não posso apagar a memória alocada, pois preciso retornar, o que eu faço?

```
const char* enc(const char* Str)
{
    auto len = strlen(Str);
    char* _Str = new char[len];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) _Str[i] = Str[i] + 4;

    _Str[len] = '\0';
    return _Str;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: meio pedante, mas identificadores parecidos com `_Aaa` são reservados para a biblioteca padrão e usar esse estilo no seu código tem comportamento indefinido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O papel do operador `new` é alocar uma região da memória (heap, não a pilha de execução) para os dados e invocar em cada célula o construtor daquele tipo de dado. Isso significa que cada vez que se executa o operador `new` se ocupa mais memória e, como memória tem limite, não se pode chamar `new` a vontade sem usar `delete` antes de faltar memória para outro `new`.

Programas que precisam fazer muitas alocações de memória (como programas de matemática simbólica, servidores web e outros), precisam administrar bem a memória, logo eliminam dados já desnecessários para caso aquela região da memória seja necessária para algo mais tarde. Programas comuns que precisam alocar muitos dados também podem ter problemas como esse, mas é menos comum.

Normalmente, em C++ os dados alocados num escopo são desalocados no mesmo, o que é uma boa prática de programação baseada no controle de tempo de vida de variáveis e garante a desalocação de dados não mais necessários. Em casos de dados que precisam persistir em escopos acima, os dados são construídos já nas variáveis do escopo original ou copiados para elas.

Para facilitar esse controle do tempo de vida, costuma-se utilizar construtor de estruturas e objetos de classes com a finalidade de alocar os dados sempre que os objetos são criados e também o destrutor para deletá-los, praticamente automatizando o controle do tempo de vida dos dados alocados na heap sem precisar lembrar de usar `new` e `delete` na hora certa.

Com isso, você poderia fazer uma estrutura assim.

```
struct StringType {
private:
    char *strChars ;
    size_t strLen ;
    void constroy( size_t len ){
        strChars = new char[ (strLen=len)+1 ] ;
    }
    void constroyCopy( const StringType &string ){
        constroy( string.StrLen ) ;
        for( size_t index=0 ; index<=StrLen ; index++ ){
            StrChars[index] = string.StrChars[index] ;
        }
    }
    void destroy( void ){
        delete strChars ;
    }
public:
    ~StringType( void ){
        destroy() ;
    }
    StringType( size_t maxLength ){
        constroy(maxLength) ;
    }
    StringType( const StringType &string ){
        constroyCopy(string) ;
    }
    resetString( size_t newMaxLength ){
        destroy() ;
        constroy(newMaxLength ) ;
    }
    resetString( const StringType &string ){
        destroy() ;
        constroyCopy(string) ;
    }
    size_t length( void ){
        return strLen ;
    }
    const char* charPointer( void ){
        return strChars ;
    }
}
```

E então se quiser que os dados persistam por cópia você faz uma função que retorna a estrutura, aí ela será copiada.

```
StringType char* enc( const char* Str ){
    StringType _Str( strlen(Str) ) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<_Str.length() ; i++ ) _Str.charPointer[i] = Str[i]+4 ;
    _Str.charPointer[len] = '\0';
    return _Str ;
}
```

Mas se você prefere um desempenho melhor você pode salvar os dados diretamente numa estrutura de destino passando seu endereço como argumento.

```
void enc( const char* Str , String *Str_out ){
    Str_out.resetString( strlen(Str) ) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<Str_out.length() ; i++ ) Str_out.charPointer[i] = Str[i]+4 ;
    Str_out.charPointer[len] = '\0';
}
```

Observação: neste trecho do seu código

```
auto len = strlen(Str);
char* _Str = new char[len];
```

você alocou células de índice `0, 1, ..., len-1` e neste

```
_Str[len] = '\0';
```

você salvou na célula de índice `len`, que não existe. Para evitar possíveis erros (como o caso de ter outra coisa alocada nessa regição da memória que será perdida), aloque uma célula a mais. Nos códigos que fiz, já automatizei isso alocando `(strLen=len)+1` células na construção da estrutura de tipo string.

Alguma dúvida?

Edit: há uma solução alternativa que conserva a sua forma de programar, não requer uma estrutura implementada e deve ter um desempenho melhor. Basta você adicionar um parâmetro que é array de caracteres de destino para que você escreva nele a solução ao invés de alocar e retornar um array de caracteres. Com isso, você tem todo o controle de criação e remoção dos dados por fora da função, podendo envolver escopos ou outro critério que você considere mais adequado.

```
void enc( const char* Str , char* _Str_out ){
    size_t len = strlen(Str) ;
    for( size_t i=0 ; i<len ; i++ ) _Str_out[i] = Str[i]+4 ;
    _Str_out[len] = '\0';
}
```

Mais uma coisa, você pode fazer isso sem precisar chamar a função que conta o número de caracteres da string, assim melhorando mais o desempenho.

```
void enc( const char* Str , char* _Str_out ){
    size_t i ;
    for( i=0 ; Str[i]!='\0' ; i++ ) _Str_out[i] = Str[i]+4 ;
    _Str_out[i] = '\0' ;
}
```

Comment: Uma outra alternativa que eu descobri, seria usar um array dentro da função como static e com um tamanho do array grande para evitar estouros, como 4096 por exemplo e retorna ela.

Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Tem essa também, que é bem eficiente mas não dá controle do tamanho do array. Isso nós costumamos chamar de buffer e deve tomar cuidado para não usar muitos buffers ao longo do programa e engordar demais o executável na memória, deixando-o pesado em execução.

Answer (score 5):

O "problema" é que cada vez que a função é chamada, mais memória é usada. O problema na verdade é maior se o seu programa vai funcionar como um servidor ou outro tipo de processo de longa duração, e ficar executando por horas/dias - e a cada chamada da função vai usar um pouco mais de memória.

Se for um programa rápido, de interação no terminal, que faz alguma coisa e termina, não há problema - exceto pela violação de boas práticas de programação.

Agora, o interessante é o seguinte: na verdade em sistemas mesmo de complexidade mediana, o normal é funções que "criam" objetos que vão ser usados em outros pontos no programa não desalocarem essa memória. É responsabilidade do código que chamou a função que cria um objeto alocando memória destruir o objeto criado. O que fazer em cada caso deve estar na documentação da sua função.

Nesse caso, você só cria uma string - então é só documentar que quem chamar essa função deve fazer um  `delete` depois de usar o valor de retorno - O c++ na verdade vai destruir a string sozinha se ela sair de escopo no código de onde foi chamada - e isso acontece para strings ou outros objetos.  Se o código fosse C puro, quem usasse sua função teria que ser instruído ou a chamar uma função para destruir o objeto explícitamente (necessário para structs contendo ponteiros para outras structs, por exemplo), ou chamar diretamente a função `free`. (Em C++, o comando `delete` ou a saída do escopo chamam o `destructor` do objeto - um método especial que faz essa ação).

Comment: Mesmo documentando isso, muita gente não lê, ou pode acabar esquecendo de liberar essa memória, não acho que isso seria uma boa solução para o problema.

Obrigado pela dica e solução.

Comment: Como você pode ver, em C++ não é um problema. Já a documentação é a forma correta sim - por que em C e C++ você tem que saber o que fazer com qualquer objeto que esteja lidando no seu código. Se recebeu uma string válida, tem que olhar se ela foi criada com `new` ou com  `malloc` -  faz parte de programar nessas linguagens.  (em geral uma base de código em C++ bem comportado sempre vai entregar objetos criados com `new` que se apagam - mas quem usa as funções _tem_ que saber o que fazer)

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você usou `auto` então você deve estar usando pelo menos C++11 então você pode considerar retornar um `std::unique_ptr` que garante que só existe uma cópia do ponteiro. Assim, o usuário da sua função não precisa se preocupar com isso porque a deleção é feita automaticamente quando o ponteiro sair de escopo.

Um pouco fora do tópico, considerando também o uso de C++11 (ou maior) você deve evitar ao máximo o uso de ponteiros "raw".

Comment: Acho que para uma função simples como essa, não seja necessário o uso de "smart pointers".

Comment: @cYeR talvez não para essa função (embora seja uma forma de romper com a parte do C++ que dá problema) porém é importante saber que tem mais essa alternativa.